# How to force Android build script to place native libraries into the correct library folders according its eabi version?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an application which uses native libraries for various targets – ARMv6, ARMv6+vfp, ARM7+vfp, ARM7+Neon, ARM7 + Tegra as well as some universal libraries. My goal is to pack all the libraries into one .apk file so that I don’t have to distribute separate builds – I don’t care a much about the total .apk size.

Here is my Android.mk script – just an example but with enough info:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi
LOCAL_MODULE := prebuilt_arm_v6vfp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../bin/libplayer_v6vfp.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := ../libplayer_v6vfp.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
LOCAL_MODULE := prebuilt_arm_v7n
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../bin/libplayer_v7n.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := ../libplayer_v7n.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := player

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := some_cpp_sources...

LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/../bin
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz -lm -lplayer_v7n -lplayer_v6vfp
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Now I have the following problem – it creates `libs` folder with `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a` subfolders – that’s OK. But the content of both subfolders is the same, both contains libplayer_v7n.so and libplayer_v6vfp.so as well.

How can I assure each subfolder contains only a correct version of native library according to its eabi version?

**EDIT 1:**

As you can see, I link libplayer.so with both shared libraries, they have compatible interfaces. I wanted to select the correct library dynamically when loading in my Java wrapper after detecting the CPU type. But it seems it is not possible. Any idea how to choose the correct library dynamically? There must be a solution for such a common case.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems I can link my libplayer.so only with one library and have to select its correct version at runtime. But now the problem is how to store six native libraries of various versions but with the same name in the lib folder. Subfolders seem to be an obvious solution, but I am not sure it is possible. The other solution would be to deploy the correct library via the separate .apk as a plug-in, but that’s exactly I want to avoid..

Comment: But you are linking your libplayer.so to both shared libraries - so it needs to have both of them in same folder. Right?

Comment: Yes, I link my libplayer.so with both shared libraries, they have compatible interfaces. I want to select the correct library dynamically when loading in my Java wrapper after detecting the CPU type; I hope it is possible...

Comment: I think you are going about this wrong. Instead of linking libplayer with the various ABI's, why not create static libraries for the various platforms and use the NDK to build a libplayer linked against each of the specialized static (.a) files. This will result in the NDK placing a ABI-appropriate libplayer.so in the various folders. From there loadLibrary() will pick and choose the correct binary.

Comment: Yes, it could solve the problem, but I am not able to do so because of legal reasons – LGPL license... I have to use dynamic linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then do the following:

1. name architecture specific libraries with same name (for example: libplayer_arch.so) & put them in different directories.
2. link libplayer.so to libplayer_arch.so
3. write your Java code like this:

.

```
if (isArmv7())
{
    System.loadLibrary("armv7/libplayer_arch.so");
}
else
{
    System.loadLibrary("armv6/libplayer_arch.so");
}
System.loadLibrary("libplayer.so");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right; I realized what’s wrong a bit later after your answer – see EDIT 2. Is it possible to create subfolders in the libs folder with Android.mk script (except armeabi and armeabi –v7a)? I don’t think so.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that from Android.mk make script. If you want to keep the name different you could load libraries dynamically at runtime using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose functions.

Comment: It is easy to load the correct version in the native side using dlopen/dlsym/dlclose functions. But I still don’t know how to create subdirs in libs/armeabi and armeabi-v7a. I can do this only manually by changing the final apk using 7zip utility, which breaks the app sign...